# Inequality in $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis

I am just beginning to learn about $L^p$ spaces and am using Folland.

$\textbf{Proposition 6.10:}$ If $0 < p < q < r \le \infty$, then $L^p \cap L^r \subset L^q$ and $||f||_q \le ||f||_p^{\lambda}||f||_r^{1 - \lambda}$, where $\lambda \in (0,1)$ is defined by $$ \frac1q = \lambda \frac1p + ( 1 - \lambda) \frac1r$$ and $$ \lambda= \frac{ \frac1q - \frac1r}{\frac1p - \frac1r}$$

In the proof the following inequality is made, if $r= \infty$, we have that $|f|^q \le ||f||_{\infty}^{q-p} | f|^p$

Where is this inequality coming from?

Comment: Do you recall the definition of $\|f\|_{\infty}$?

Comment: Just a short explanation would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

By definition,
$$ | f(x) | \leqslant \| f \|_{\infty} = \operatorname{ess sup}_{x} | f(x) |. $$
Raising both sides to the positive power $q-p$ does not change the sense of the inequality, so 
$$ |f(x)|^{q-p} \leqslant \| f \|_{\infty}^{q-p}, $$
and then multiplying by the nonnegative number $| f(x) |^p $ gives what you want.